# Xamarin Service and Forms Init

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite.net

I'm writing a Xamarin Android application that consists of service and a page for configuration.
The service starts after device boot (launched by a **BroadcastReceiver**) and needs a database connection to read the configuration.
I receive an error when the service tries to read the database:

> You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it.

For the database connection, I'm using **SQLite.Net**.
I know that I need to call the **Xamarin.Forms.Init()** to use the database, but I don't know how I can do it. The Init() method needs context and **Android.OS.Bundle** as inputs, but in the BroadcastReceiver class, I have only the context. How I can retrieve the bundle? Is there another way to do that?

This is the exception stacktrace:

> ```
> at Xamarin.Forms.Device.get_PlatformServices () 
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Device.GetAssemblies () 
>   at Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Initialize () 
>   at Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get[T] (Xamarin.Forms.DependencyFetchTarget fetchTarget) 
>   at MyProject.Database.ConfigurationDBService..ctor () 
>   at MyProject.Utils.ConfigurationUtils.getConfig () 
>   at MyProject.InvoiceUploadService.OnStartCommand (Android.Content.Intent intent, Android.App.StartCommandFlags flags,System.Int32 startId)
> ```

Comment: Make your `Service` independent of `Xamarin.Forms` (you do not need an Init'd Forms App for a SQLite connection.)

Comment: How I can do that? I think that now I need Xamarin.Forms because for the database connection I use a DependencyService

Comment: The Forms' DependencyService is calling "native" code, your Android Service is already running in "native" code. What ever code your DS is using for Android you can use without a DS.

Comment: I don't know... I added the exception stacktrace in the post. Can it be useful?

Comment: Do not use the DependencyService at all, you are already running Android code in your service, use the Android code that your DependencyService would call.

Comment: I solved the problem by running the database connection without a DependecyService as you suggested. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working 

Comment: If you want you can write the solution as answer, so I can flag it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by running the database connection without a DependecyService as suggested by SushiHangover in the question's comments.

Answer (score -2):

Put:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Init();
```

In your MainActivity.cs class in Android Project.

Comment: The Forms.Init is already present in MainActivity.cs. If I start the application with double click in the icon than all works correctly. The problem is that the service starts not through MainActivity.