# Android Xamarin - Opening Scheduled Notification Stops the Repeat and Crashes When Using SQLite

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have created a Xamarin Android application that has 6 database tables by using SQLite. I have implemented a repeating notification feature that displays a different element from the SQLite table every time a notification is called. This is done by having the app run in the background and going through the SQL data to find the element to display in the notification. If the notification is tapped, the application is opened and  the displayed information in the notification is shown on a page on the application.

So what I can do is open my application and set it to show repeating notification. The notifications display different information every time it is fired based off the background functions going through my SQL data. I exit my app and clear my recent applications to have it run in the background. The notification and changing information works great. But once I re-open the application the notifications stops firing and moments later when I close my app, I get notified that the app has stopped responding.

I believe the problem comes from the Android Alarm Services and the SQLite data connection. How do I keep my notifications to continuously repeat even after I have opened the application again? If I never open the application again after initially setting up the notifications to show, the notifications continue to display without error.

This is my class that sets up the alarm manager and creates notifications

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(LawsForImpact.Droid.AndroidNotificationManager))]
namespace LawsForImpact.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    public class AndroidNotificationManager : BroadcastReceiver, INotificationManager
    {
        const string channelId = "default";
        const string channelName = "Default";
        const string channelDescription = "The default channel for notifications.";
        const int pendingIntentId = 0;

        public const string LocalNotificationKey = "LocalNotification";

        public const string TableKey = "table";
        public const string IndexKey = "index";

        bool channelInitialized = false;
        int messageId = -1;
        NotificationManager manager;

        public event EventHandler NotificationReceived;

        string currentTitle;
        int currentIndex;
        SavedInformation savedInfo;

        public void Initialize()
        {
            CreateNotificationChannel();
        }

        public int ScheduleNotification(string title, string message)
        {
            if (!channelInitialized)
            {
                CreateNotificationChannel();
            }

            messageId++;

            // 1 MainActivity intent allows MainActivity to change once notification tapped
            Intent intentMain = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(MainActivity));

            intentMain.PutExtra(TableKey, currentTitle);
            intentMain.PutExtra(IndexKey, currentIndex);


            PendingIntent pendingIntentMain = PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId, intentMain, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle textStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntentMain)
                .SetContentTitle(title)
                .SetContentText(message)
                .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(AndroidApp.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.ic_mtrl_chip_checked_circle))
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_mtrl_chip_checked_black)
                .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
                .SetStyle(textStyle);

            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

            Notification notification = builder.Build();
            manager.Notify(randomNumber, notification);


            return messageId;
        }



        public void SavedInfo(SerializableDictionary<string, int> pickedQueue, int queueIndex, bool randomTog, int repeatInterval)
        {
            savedInfo = new SavedInformation();

            currentTitle = pickedQueue.ElementAt(queueIndex).Key;

            savedInfo.QueueOfSaved = pickedQueue;
            savedInfo.QueueIndex = queueIndex;

            savedInfo.RandomToggle = randomTog;
            savedInfo.RepeatInterval = repeatInterval;

            LoadData();
            RepeatAlarmSet();
        }


        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            var extra = intent.GetStringExtra(LocalNotificationKey);
            var notification = DeserializeNotification(extra);

            SerializableDictionary<string, int> queue = notification.QueueOfSaved;
            var queueIndex = notification.QueueIndex;

            var randTog = notification.RandomToggle;
            var repInterval = notification.RepeatInterval;

            SavedInfo(queue, queueIndex, randTog, repInterval);

        }



        public void RepeatAlarmSet()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(AndroidNotificationManager));
            var serializedNotification = SerializeNotification(savedInfo);
            intent.PutExtra(LocalNotificationKey, serializedNotification);

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
            alarmManager.SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, 1000, pendingIntent);
        }

        public void Cancel()
        {


            var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(AndroidNotificationManager));
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
            pendingIntent.Cancel();
            alarmManager.Cancel(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
            notificationManager.CancelAll();
        }


        private async void LoadData()
        {
             SQLiteConnection _sqLiteConnection;
            _sqLiteConnection = await Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
            IEnumerable<IDataTable> tableToEnumerable = new List<IDataTable>();
            List<IDataTable> listData;

            switch (currentTitle)
            {
                case "Table1":
                    tableToEnumerable = _sqLiteConnection.Table<Table1>().ToList();
                    break;
                case "Table2":
                    tableToEnumerable = _sqLiteConnection.Table<Table2>().ToList();
                    break;
                case "Table3":
                    tableToEnumerable = _sqLiteConnection.Table<Table3>().ToList();
                    break;
                case "Table4":
                    tableToEnumerable = _sqLiteConnection.Table<Table4>().ToList();
                    break;
                case "Table5":
                    tableToEnumerable = _sqLiteConnection.Table<Table5>().ToList();
                    break;
                case "Table6":
                    tableToEnumerable = _sqLiteConnection.Table<Table6>().ToList();
                    break;
            }
            listData = tableToEnumerable.ToList();

            int index = listData.Count() - savedInfo.QueueOfSaved[currentTitle];
            index = index - 1;
            currentIndex = index;



            // if random enabled
            if (savedInfo.RandomToggle)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                index = random.Next(0, listData.Count());
            }


            //sets all the current notification information
            string title = listData[index].Title;
            string message = listData[index].Description;

            //logic for next notification


            // subtract the queue int of current notification subject to keep track of next index
            savedInfo.QueueOfSaved[currentTitle] = savedInfo.QueueOfSaved[currentTitle] - 1;

            // check for index overflow
            if (savedInfo.QueueOfSaved[currentTitle] < 0)
            {
                savedInfo.QueueOfSaved[currentTitle] = listData.Count() - 1;
            }


            // index of next table
            savedInfo.QueueIndex = savedInfo.QueueIndex + 1;


            // if next table index overflows that means its time to restart the table index and move up the notification index
            if (savedInfo.QueueIndex >= savedInfo.QueueOfSaved.Count)
            {
                savedInfo.QueueIndex = 0;
            }

            ScheduleNotification(title, message);
        }


        public void ReceiveNotification(string table, int index)
        {
            var args = new NotificationEventArgs()
            {
                Table = table,
                Index = index,
            };
            NotificationReceived?.Invoke(null, args);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
            notificationManager.CancelAll();
        }

        public static Intent GetLauncherActivity()
        {

            var packageName = Application.Context.PackageName;
            return Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        }

        void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            manager = (NotificationManager)AndroidApp.Context.GetSystemService(AndroidApp.NotificationService);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                var channelNameJava = new Java.Lang.String(channelName);
                var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelNameJava, NotificationImportance.Default)
                {
                    Description = channelDescription
                };
                manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            channelInitialized = true;
        }

        private string SerializeNotification(SavedInformation notification)
        {

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(notification.GetType());

            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, notification);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }

        private SavedInformation DeserializeNotification(string notificationString)
        {

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SavedInformation));
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(notificationString))
            {
                var notification = (SavedInformation)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
                return notification;
            }
        }

        private AlarmManager GetAlarmManager()
        {
            var alarmManager = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
            return alarmManager;
        }
    }
```

I believe the MainActivity is somehow involved as it responsible for the process in restarting my application.

```
[Activity(
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, 
        Label = "LawsForImpact",
        Icon = "@mipmap/icon", 
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme", 
        MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]

    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            LoadApplication(new App());

            CreateNotificationFromIntent(Intent);

        }

        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            CreateNotificationFromIntent(intent);
        }

        void CreateNotificationFromIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent?.Extras != null)
            {
                string tableKey = intent.Extras.GetString(AndroidNotificationManager.TableKey);
                int indexKey = intent.Extras.GetInt(AndroidNotificationManager.IndexKey);

                DependencyService.Get<INotificationManager>().ReceiveNotification(tableKey, indexKey);
            }
        }



        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you re-open the application you will setp into `OnNenIntent` ,method,then it will call `DependencyService.Get<INotificationManager>().ReceiveNotification(tableKey, indexKey);` to cancel the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having came from when I was loading my SQL data during the background process. The Dependency Service was causing the issue. I figured this out by using the Android Device Monitor tool and with the help of: [Xamarin Service and Forms Init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741574/xamarin-service-and-forms-init)